# how to get Https Response Code from Android without SSL key

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I need to communicate with a wepsite over Https protocol with my android App.

when I use any browser like Chrome or Firefox I have no problem at all and everything worked as wished.

but when I want to do the same in my App using this snippt of code:

```
try {
   URL url = new URL("https://justExample.de" + result);

   HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   connection.connect();
   code = connection.getResponseCode(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and In Manifest :

I got an `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

To make it work I need to add the `crt` and `key`(should get from website developer) as raw data and in manifest should the following line in application added:
`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

and create a xml file named `network_security_config`,which contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/crt"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Now my question how can I get the content\ResponseCode without this crt\key ? the same like chrome and other browsers.

The Second question, what should the web developer make from his side to let me get the content without the key\cret

Comment: "how can I get the content\ResponseCode without this crt\key ?" -- that depends a lot on what the actual problem is with the site's current SSL certificate (is it self-signed? is it signed by a really new certificate authority and your Android device is really old? etc.). "what should the web developer make from his side to let me get the content without the key\cret" -- use an SSL certificate authority that your device supports.

Comment: @Darkman: changing TLS versions will not fix certificate validation problems. The validation of the certificate is independent from the used TLS protocol version.